# Deployment of Model into Java Application

Tags: tensorflow, keras, u-net

Over the past few months, I have developed and tested a TensorFlow U-Net model based on the Keras Functional API. Recently I have been interested in deploying this model for use in a Java application that would run mainly on laptops and PCs preferably offline. Does anyone know a way I could potentially host my model on this Java Application? I have both a TFLite model and a regular Saved Model; however, I prefer to use the normal Saved Model. I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction or show me a good tool to deploy my model.